# Android JSON object creation

Tags: java, android

How to create a JSON object, in Android using java code.

```
{
    "apikey": "example apikey",
    "id": "example id",
    "email": {
        "email": "example email",
        "euid": "example euid",
        "leid": "example leid"
            }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create json you mentioned in question as below :

```
 public void createJson() {
        try {
            // create outer json
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("apikey", "example api key");
            jsonObject.put("id", "example id");

            // create email json
            JSONObject emailJsonObject = new JSONObject();
            emailJsonObject.put("email", "email");
            emailJsonObject.put("euid", "euid");
            emailJsonObject.put("leid", "leid");

            // add email json to outer json
            jsonObject.put("email", emailJsonObject);

            System.out.println("-----printing json------" + jsonObject.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Thanks..!!

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("apikey","example apikey");
jsonObject.put("id","example id");

JSONObject innerObject = new JSONObject();

innerObject.put("email","example email");
....
jsonObject.put("email",innerObject);
```

and to convert to String you can do like `jsonObject.toString();`

Answer (score 1):

Do like thist.

```
JSONObject myJson = new JSONObject();
myJson.put("apikey","example apikey");
myJson.put("id","example id");

JSONObject emailObject = new JSONObject();
emailObject.put("email","example email");
emailObject.put("euid","example euid");
emailObject.put("leid","example leid");

myJson.put("email",emailObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class with the constructor you want.
Likes:

```
class MyJsonObj{
  public string apikey;
  public string id;
  public string[] email;
}
```

Then instance the class

```
MyJsonObj myObj = new MyJsonObj();
myObj.apikey = "testKey";
myObj.id = "0123";
myObj.email = new string[]{"01@gamil.com","02@gmail.com"};
```

Last, convert to json string by Gson library

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(myObj);
```